# Set of rational numbers having denominator $D$

Tags: notation

The set of rational numbers is customarily denoted $\mathbb{Q}$. I need a symbol for the set of rational numbers having denominator $D$. For example, for $D = 3$, this set would be
$$\{ \cdots, -4/3, -3/3, -2/3, -1/3, 0/3, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 4/3, \cdots \}.$$

I am considering adopting the notation $\mathbb{Q}_D$, but I wanted to ask **if there is a standard or more widely recognized symbol for this set.**

- If so, what is it?
- If not, what symbol should I use?
- Is it necessary to clarify explicitly that my set includes rational numbers in "unsimplified" form (e.g. $3/3$ in the example above)?

Comment: There is a notation for the rational numbers whose denominator is a power of $3$, that notation is $\mathbb Z[1/3]$. The idea is that $\mathbb Z[1/3]$ is the smallest subring of $\mathbb Q$ that contains $\mathbb Z$ and $1/3$. But your subset, while it is an additive subgroup, is not a subring; I don't think there's any standard notation for it.

Comment: There is the notation $\,3\mathbb Z\,$ for multiples of $\,3\,$, so maybe $\,\frac{1}{3} \mathbb Z\,$ or $\,\mathbb Z/3\,$ could be used for your set. However, that notation has potential for confusion, and would have to be clearly defined before being used.

Comment: Thanks. $\mathbb{Z}/3$ was also suggested to me by a colleague, and I like this notation because it makes it possible to put a more complicated expression in the place of $3$ without destroying the legibility. (You should consider turning your comment into an answer. There is no rule against short answers.)

Comment: @Max Posted as an answer, with some additional comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\,n\mathbb Z\,$ used for integer multiples of $\,n\,$ could suggest a symmetrical notation $\,\mathbb Z/n\,$ for rational fractions with denominator $\,n\,$. This would also make it clear that the numerator is unrestricted, so the set would include fractions where a common factor might cancel out, for example $\,\frac{n}{n} = 1 \in \mathbb Z /n\,$.

One problem with this notation is that, in certain contexts at least, it would conflict with the traditional use of $\,\mathbb Z / I\,$ for [quotient groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Examples) (or [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)). In simple cases, the ambiguity could be resolved from the context alone, for example $\,\mathbb Z / 3\,$ could only mean the set of fractions with denominator $\,3\,$, while $\,\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z\,$ could only mean the ring of integers $\bmod 3\,$. However, this wouldn't always work in more complex cases, for example $\,\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)\,$ could mean either the set of rational functions with denominator $\,x^2+1\,$ and the numerator a polynomial with integer coefficients, or the ring of polynomials $\,\bmod (x^2+1)\,$.

The notation could maybe use a symbol other than "$/$" to disambiguate, for example $\,\frac{\mathbb Z}{3}\,$ or $\,\mathbb Z \div 3\,$, though neither look too "*natural*".